# How to remove envelope from Indicator applet without uninstalling the indicator-messages package?

Tags: indicator

I am tired of the envelope in the indicator applet (also known as the messages menu) because I don't use it so I would like to get rid of it but I don't have root access so I can't remove it by uninstalling the indicator-messages package. Is there another way to disable this applet?

Doesn't the indicator applet offer a way to select which indicator is displayed or not?

Comment: Have you tried, right click >> "Remove from panel" is that what you want?

Comment: @Decio, No. That removes the whole indicator applet, not just the messages indicator. I still need other indicators like the sound indicator.

Comment: When I had a similar problem, the only way I was able to resolve it was to place a tiny 'don't panic!' sticker over the offending icon.

Answer (score 10):

If you just want the messaging menu to hide you can blacklist all of the applications that are in it.  You can do that by copying all the application links to your local black list directory.  Here is the command line way to do that:

```
  mkdir -p ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist
  cp /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/* ~/.config/indicators/messages/applications-blacklist
```

The first time you create the blacklist directory you'll need to restart your session (log out and back in) and then the messaging menu should hide itself.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I still get the applet.

Answer (score 3):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1470786 according to this you can go to karmic like applet by removing indicator-applet from panel and adding gnome-volume-control-applet in startup application

Comment: That is one workaround, thanks, however I believe the indicator applet might come in handy in the future, since it is becoming a rather central point in Ubuntu and everything. I would rather not remove it all ;) Starting to think there is no solution without diving in the code/opening a suggestion on launchpad.

Answer (score 2):

Based on Riccardo Murri's answer (Sep 8 '10 at 13:19) I have checked the code and noticed that only modules that end in `.so` are loaded from `INDICATOR_DIR` (`/usr/lib/indicators/3`).

```
if (!g_str_has_suffix(name, G_MODULE_SUFFIX)) {
   return FALSE;
}
```

So

```
cd /usr/lib/indicators/3; sudo mv libmessaging.so libmessaging.so.disabled
```

did the trick for me on 10.04, Lucid.

Comment: In 12.04, the directory has become `/usr/lib/indicators3/7`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of indicator-applet-0.3.7, it seems you cannot:
every installed module in some "INDICATOR_DIR" (it's
`/usr/lib/indicators/3` on my 10.04 box) is loaded.  The
"INDICATOR_DIR" is defined as a compile-time constant, so there is no
way to change it on a installed system.  The relevant source is at
lines 703--728 in `applet-main.c`:

```
    /* load 'em */
    if (g_file_test(INDICATOR_DIR, (G_FILE_TEST_EXISTS | G_FILE_TEST_IS_DIR))) {
            GDir * dir = g_dir_open(INDICATOR_DIR, 0, NULL);

            const gchar * name;
            while ((name = g_dir_read_name(dir)) != NULL) {
                    /* ... some lines omitted for brevity ... */
                    if (load_module(name, menubar)) {
                            indicators_loaded++;
                    }
            }
            g_dir_close (dir);
    }
```

As a workaround, you could (warning: *untested!*):

1. compile your own version of `indicator-applet`, specifying a
    different "INDICATOR_DIR": if you pass
    `--enable-localinstall` to `./configure`, then "INDICATOR_DIR"
    will be located in `$libdir/indicators/2` and you can also set
    `$libdir` via command-line options to `./configure`.
2. within your own INDICATOR_DIR, only activate the indicators you
    want (just symlinking the system-wide ones should suffice)
3. use a `~/.gnomerc` or `~/.xsession` file to modify PATH so that 
    your own `indicator-applet` binary comes before the system-wide
    one.