# How can I add the volume/sound manager to my panel

Tags: 10.10, sound, panel

Somehow I don't have the sound manager in my panel on Ubuntu 10.10. How can I add it? It is not in the list of panels that I can add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no 'sound only' indicator, you have to place the Indicator Applet (not indicator-applet-session) on your panel. It will add two icons, the speaker and the envelope. If anyone figures out a way to have ONLY the sound icon please post a reply, this annoys me.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/3832/how-to-remove-envelope-from-indicator-applet-without-uninstalling-the-indicator-m/3846#3846 here are some workarounds. Haven't tested for maverick though...

Answer (score 0):

Sound manager or applet is part of indicator-sound or indicator applet in ubuntu.
 Check if you have indicator-sound package installed. Also see if indicator-applet is activated or installed.

Comment: I think it is installed, `whereis indicator-sound` gives /usr/lib/indicator-sound. How can I see or it is activated? And how can I activate it?

Comment: check in system monitor if indicator-sound-service is running or not. sometimes rebooting/ killing gnome-panel or even removing current indicator applet and adding a new one brings sound indicator back.

Comment: Adding the indicator Applet again restored it! Thanks!

Comment: @Peter Welcome :)

Answer (score -1):

you can add it...
create command in startup application

```
gnome-volume-control-applet
```

Comment: That would be the old pre-ayatana volume applet, not the default sound menu.