# How do I stop empathy from adding an icon in the panel?

Tags: unity, empathy

Empathy displays a menu in the "system tray" or unity top panel. So in addition to having new messages show up in the message menu, I also have this big ugly green talk bubble pop up. How can I get that to stop, so that it's just the message menu that I have to look at?

This is on 11.10, by the way.

Comment: this icon did not show up in 11.04

Comment: Could be related to this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/54429/24489

Comment: Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/3832/how-to-remove-envelope-from-indicator-applet-without-uninstalling-the-indicator and http://askubuntu.com/questions/68757/can-you-disable-the-envelope-icon-in-the-panel-without-removing-it

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, I suggest filing a feature request on launchpad or brainstorm.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)