# Can you disable the envelope icon in the panel without removing it?

Tags: messaging-menu

I wish to disable the envelope icon in 11.10's menu bar.  I do not want to remove it permanently from the computer.

With previous versions, I could right-click those type icons to make them go away, but I cannot find out how to do that in 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to disable the envelope I know is by uninstalling the indicator wich is no big deal as you can revert your changes in the same easy way.

`sudo apt-get remove indicator-messages`

to remove the indicator.

`sudo apt-get install indicator-messages`

to get it back again.

Comment: This is a [duplicate question](http://askubuntu.com/q/3832/27554) however the OP stated he didn't want to remove/uninstall it. Which I don't think is possible.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read well enough. Edited my ansewering post to better fit his question.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple way: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YggmPX_L1Is

Comment: The link is for Backtrack. Backtrack doesn't use Unity.